# Tkinter radiobuttons not selecting properly

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to make a small tkinter program to calculate the area of shapes and volumes
and I've made a main py file "area_volume_calculator.py" and two libraries "area.py" and "volume.py"

The main program's radio buttons work fine, but when I create the second window from `Area_calculator` I can't seem to get radio buttons to work properly. When it opens, the last 2 radio buttons are selected already.

I can still select an option but self.choice.get() always returns the default value which is -1, I don't know how to get it to work.

Can anyone help me get the radio buttons to work properly?
Any and all help is appreciated

Main Program:

```
from tkinter import *

from area import *

# from volume import *

class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Areas and Volumes")
    
    
        # self.name_label = Label(self.window, text = "Name: ")
        # self.name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
        # self.name_entry = Entry(self.window)
        # self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
    
        # self.age_label = Label(self.window, text = "Age: ")
        # self.age_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
    
        # self.age_entry = Entry(self.window)
        # self.age_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
    
        self.choice = IntVar()
    
        self.area_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Area Calculator", var = self.choice, value = 0)
        self.area_radiobutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
        self.volume_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Volume Calculator", var = self.choice, value = 1)
        self.volume_radiobutton.grid(row=3,column=0)
    
        self.choice.set(-1)
    
        self.submit_button = Button(self.window, text = "Submit", command = self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4,column=0)
    
        print(self.choice.get())
    
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def submit(self):
        print(self.choice.get())

        if self.choice.get() == 0:
            area_calculator = Area_calculator()
    
        # elif self.choice.get() == 1:
        #     volume_calculator = Volume_calculator()


menu = Menu()
```

area.py library:

```
from tkinter import *
class Area_calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title
        self.window.title("Area Calculator")
    
        self.choice_label = Label(self.window, text = "Choose a shape")
        self.choice_label.grid(row=0,columnspan=1)
    
        self.choice = IntVar()
    
        self.rectangle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Rectangle", var = self.choice, value = 0)
        self.rectangle_radiobutton.grid(row=1,column=0)
    
        self.triangle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Triangle", var = self.choice, value = 1)
        self.triangle_radiobutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
        self.circle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Circle", var = self.choice, value = 2)
        self.circle_radiobutton.grid(row=3,column=0)
    
        self.submit_button = Button(self.window, text = "Submit", command = self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4,column=0)
    
        self.choice.set(-1)
        print(self.choice.get())
    
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def submit(self):
        print(self.choice.get())
#        if self.choice.get() == 0:
#            rectangle_calculator = Rectangle_calculator()
#        elif self.choice.get() == 1:
#            triangle_calculator = Triangle_calculator()
#        elif self.choice.get() == 2:
#            circle_calculator = Circle_calculator()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two instances of `tk.Tk()` (one in each class) which is never a good idea. `tk.Tk()` does not just create a new window but also a new embedded Tcl interpreter and this can mess things up, particularly `IntVar`s and other variables such as `self.choice`. For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged).

If you want to have multiple windows then use `tk.Toplevel()` instead.

In answer to your second question in the comments, you must first add the parameters `name` and `age` to the `__init__` of the `Area_calculator` class, and also pass them to the class when creating it in `Menu`.

Completed code:

**Main program:**

```py
from tkinter import *

from area import *


class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Areas and Volumes")
    
        self.name_label = Label(self.window, text = "Name: ")
        self.name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
        self.name_entry = Entry(self.window)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
    
        self.age_label = Label(self.window, text = "Age: ")
        self.age_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
    
        self.age_entry = Entry(self.window)
        self.age_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
    
        self.choice = IntVar()
    
        self.area_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Area Calculator", var = self.choice, value = 0)
        self.area_radiobutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
        self.volume_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Volume Calculator", var = self.choice, value = 1)
        self.volume_radiobutton.grid(row=3,column=0)
    
        self.choice.set(-1)
    
        self.submit_button = Button(self.window, text = "Submit", command = self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4,column=0)
    
        print(self.choice.get())
    
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def submit(self):
        print(self.choice.get())

        if self.choice.get() == 0:
            name = self.name_entry.get()
            age = self.age_entry.get()
            area_calculator = Area_calculator(name, age)


menu = Menu()
```

**area.py library:**

```py
from tkinter import *


class Area_calculator():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.window = Toplevel()
        self.window.title
        self.window.title("Area Calculator")

        self.name_label = Label(self.window, text = f"{name=}", width=10)
        self.name_label.grid()

        self.age_label = Label(self.window, text = f"{age=}", width=10)
        self.age_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        self.choice_label = Label(self.window, text = "Choose a shape")
        self.choice_label.grid(row=1,columnspan=1)
    
        self.choice = IntVar()
    
        self.rectangle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Rectangle", var = self.choice, value = 0)
        self.rectangle_radiobutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
        self.triangle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Triangle", var = self.choice, value = 1)
        self.triangle_radiobutton.grid(row=3,column=0)
    
        self.circle_radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.window, text = "Circle", var = self.choice, value = 2)
        self.circle_radiobutton.grid(row=4,column=0)
    
        self.submit_button = Button(self.window, text = "Submit", command = self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=5,column=0)
    
        self.choice.set(-1)
        print(self.choice.get())
    
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def submit(self):
        print(self.choice.get())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed it, also i have another question if you dont mind: in the commented code, i get 2 variables for name and age, how can i pass these variables to that i can display them to a second window? is it as simple as having   'class Area_calculator(name, age)' and executing the function from the first window?

Comment: or writing area_calculator = Area_calculator(name, age)?